# How to limit range of column? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in Districts, but I need to skip first two rows (to limit the range) of it. How to do it? My code:

```vb
Dim VComp As Variant
ReDim vOut(1 To 14, 1 To 3)
vOut(3) = Districts.Columns(2)
vOut(2) = Mid(Districts.Columns(2), 2, 1)
vOut(1) = Len(Districts.Columns(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

### 'Remove' First Rows From Range

```vb
Districts.Resize(Districts.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2).Columns(2)
```

i.e.

```
Const fRow As Long = 3
Const Col As Long = 2

Dim Districts As Range: Set Districts = Range("A1:B10")
Dim rg2 As Range

With Districts
    Set rg2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1).Columns(Col)
    ' or without the constants
    'Set rg2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2).Columns(2)
End With
```